# statistics from apim manager if gateway is installed

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

If gateway server is installed in one server and api manager installed in another server and I have configured DAS in api manager server. Will my DAS server can collect statistics data from api manager server?

Comment: What is the version of the API Manager?

Comment: it is apim 1.10 and DAS 3.0.1

Comment: I have configured apim1.10, DAS 3.0.1 in one server and gateway in other server. DAS is not able to collect the data. Is there anywhere i need to configure ipaddress of gateway or apim server in DAS? my server has ipadress and localhost will not work. Also after restarting APIM, analytics enable option in admin-dashboard is unchecked. I have to enable it every time after restart apim.

Comment: Only gateway nodes(workers) will publish stats to DAS nodes. Then DAS nodes will summerize data and write to the database. After that APIM dashboards will retrieve data from the db. You can use file based method instead of using the UI approach. - http://blog.rukspot.com/2016/05/configure-wso2-apim-analytics-using-xml.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is configuring database is mandatory? Can i use it by only REST api similar to UI method? Because i didn't configured DB and i'm not able to collect the data. i have configured DAS in gateway server. i'm not seeing any errors in the logs.

Comment: There is no activity on the server but still i see below information in logs           TID: [-1] [] [2017-03-22 11:05:11,639]  INFO {org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager} -  Starting task 0.0 in stage 30860.0 (TID 16631, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1320 bytes) {org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager}

TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-22 11:05:11,641]  INFO {org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler} -  Job 12842 finished: collect at SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:855, took 0.003591 s {org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler}

Comment: do i need to change anything in Spark configurations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gateway manager or gateway worker profile then you need to enable below OSGI bundles in bundles.info for that profile

org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.stub,4.6.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.stub_4.6.0.jar,4,true
org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.ui,4.6.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.bam.service.data.publisher.ui_4.6.0.jar,4,true
 org.wso2.carbon.statistics,4.4.8,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.statistics_4.4.8.jar,4,true
org.wso2.carbon.statistics.stub,4.4.8,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.statistics.stub_4.4.8.jar,4,true
 org.wso2.carbon.statistics.ui,4.4.8,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.statistics.ui_4.4.8.jar,4,true